# load different content using data html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know if it is possible and how can I use the html `data` attribute to load different content depending on mobile or desktop? I have set `data-gif` tag on the gif element, and the `data-video` tag on the video element.

From what I understand it is possible to load different content based on screen size, but cannot implement this. I do not want to just hide elements based on screen size, but I don't want to load them at all.

Please see my code below. I have tried many ways implement what I have described above, but with no success.

Currently this is the code I have:

```
<div id="main>
  <div class="box-one>
    <img data-gif='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/552a5cc4e4b059a56a050501/565f6b57e4b0d9b44ab87107/566024f5e4b0354e5b79dd24/1449141991793/NYCGifathon12.gif'>
    <video data-video width="640" height="360" controls="" autoplay=""><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>';
  </div>

  <div class="box-two>
    <img data-gif='http://static1.squarespace.com/static/552a5cc4e4b059a56a050501/565f6b57e4b0d9b44ab87107/566024f5e4b0354e5b79dd24/1449141991793/NYCGifathon12.gif'>
    <video data-video width="640" height="360" controls="" autoplay=""><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>';
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function(){

   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var maxDeviceWidth = 768;

   if (windowWidth > maxDeviceWidth) {
       //show video
   } else {
       //show gif
  }

})();
```

Comment: why do you want to use data attr here. use hide/show

Comment: i don't want to load the content from the server, and load different content based on screen size

Answer (score 1):

loading and showing content are two different things. If content it in the DOM, it will be loaded. You can then show/ hide the content with CSS.

```
.box-one{
    display: none;
}
.box-two{
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .box-one{
        display: block;
    }
    .box-two{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you want to only load the necessary content to the DOM, you will need to test for the screen size with JavaScript and then pull in the content with with Ajax, or hard-code it into your JavaScript.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var maxDeviceWidth = 768;
if (windowWidth > maxDeviceWidth) {
    //Server the desktop version
    //You can get the content with Ajax or load both and hide the other
} else {
    //Load the mobile content - either with Ajax, or hide the desktop content
}
```

Comment: hey tom :-), ok so i will need to use js to show the content? I cannot use a technique using the html `data` attribute? I am sure I saw this before

Comment: You don't need to use the data attribute or JavaScript. Just use CSS to show and hide content based on screen size. The data attribute is just another selector that you can use for either CSS3 or JavaScript.

Comment: ok! does show and hide stop the content being downloaded from the server?

Comment: No, the content is loaded from the server and added to the DOM. CSS simply manipulates the appearance of the DOM. by using display: none; you are simply hiding it. If you want to only load the content based on screen side, you will need to use the JavaScript component of my answer, with either Ajax, jQuery's .HTML() function or JavaScript .innerHTML.

Comment: is it not possible to use something like this - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp similar to todd motto's lazy loader https://github.com/toddmotto/echo

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer, using javascript (as in your question):

```
(function() {

   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var maxDeviceWidth = 768;

   if (windowWidth > maxDeviceWidth) {
       // show video
       document.getElementById('box-one').style.visibility = 'visible';
       document.getElementById('box-two').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   } else {
       //show gif
       document.getElementById('box-one').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       document.getElementById('box-two').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }

})();
```

The same result can be (better?) achieved using CSS media queries (see @Tom's answer)...

Also, pay attention to closing quotes in your HTML...

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the same video link in each div , so use only when need will be faster .

```
var video =  '<video data-video width="640" height="360" controls="" autoplay=""><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>';
(function(){

   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var maxDeviceWidth = 768;

   if (windowWidth > maxDeviceWidth) {
       $("div#main div").each(function(){
        $(this).append(video);
        $(this).find("img").remove();
       });
   }
})();
```